# attribute binding in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue and currently trying to dynamically change the video or image source link by passing the data in through a prop. I created a component with specific template structure that I would like to pass in the source from the main app.js page. I've tried binding it in both areas but unsure if I'm doing it correctly. I tried using regular divs and stuff to embed the video in app.js and it shows the content perfectly.

parent element contains 'Video' component-

```
<Video theme="IL" :vidSrc="srcIL.vid"></Video>

import Video from "./components/Video.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Video
  },
  data() {
    return {
      srcIL: {
        vid: "./assets/invi-lines/invisible-lines-film.mp4"
      }
     
    };
 }
```

child 'Video component'

```
<template>
  <div class="introVid top">
    <video controls :src="vidSrc"></video>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["theme", "vidSrc"]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like you have it set up properly, and it is hard to know exactly what is causing the issues from the info provided, but I'm going to make a guess that it might be that the asset is not getting bundled.

> *I tried using regular divs and stuff to embed the video in app.js and it shows the content perfectly*

I suspect you had something like:

```html
<video controls src="./assets/invi-lines/invisible-lines-film.mp4"></video>
```

which would have taken the resource from the assets and packaged it for use.
see [relative-path-imports](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports) for details.

You can try forcing these to load using `require` somewhere in the project, which will force the compiler to copy the asset, but really, if you have dynamic assets (assuming there's more than a handful and they can change) you should have them in the public folder already, not in the source folder. So my recommendation is that you move the dynamic assets to the public folder (assuming that was your issue to begin with)